# Rhino Mocks - How to assert a mocked method was called n-times?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

How can i assert that a method on a mocked object was called exactly called n-times?

Here is the code snippet from a controller action, i like to test:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= newMatchCommand.NumberOfMatchesToCreate; i++) {
    serviceFacade.CreateNewMatch("tester", Side.White);
}
```

The "service facade" object is the (strict) mock and will be injected into the controller. 
The unit test should assert that the CreateNewMatch method within the action was called n-times. (e.g. 5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Expect.Call(method).Repeat.Times(n)`.

Comment: VerfiyAll() expects you to return an object, it complainswas expecting something returned

Answer (score 43):

better yet:

```
mockObject.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SomeMethod(), opt => opt.Repeat.Times(n));
```