# Should I unit test code with no obvious returns from methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a class thats sole purpose is to run a method on other classes from an Interface.

Testing the interface of the classes is no problem, but the runner doesn't actually DO anything and (as it stands) the only parameter passed into the constructor is kept private.

In my case, the classes are importing text files into a database.

```
internal DataImporter
{
  private List<IFileImporter> _importers;

  public DataImporter(List<IFileImporter> importers){
    _importers = importers;

  public bool RunImporters()
  {
    //foreach importer, call its "Run" method - each one then does whatever it needs to do
    //however, this need not call a specific "Run" method on IFileImporter
    //I have another app that uses IFileImporter to check for presence of a file first
    //then allow user to choose to import or not.
  }
```

It seems to me there is nothing to test here?  I can't test the value of `_importers`, and I don't want to make it public JUST for the sake of testing.  DataImporter is specific to this instance, so creating an interface seems to add no benefit.

I've re-used IFileImporters elsewhere, but this is the only "bulk" importer, others are called manually from a winforms app, still others are not in this project at all.

So, do I need to test this...what CAN I test about this?

Comment: If such a void method changes the state of the object, or makes any external calls, you might still want to test it by testing the end result and not specifically the return value.

Comment: @ryadavilli - I agree. Right now im creating a unit test that deletes an object from the database. The method returns void, but i can still check if it exists in the database.

Comment: The object is effectively the "Main" method, but with a strongly typed List<...> instead of params.  Each of the 30 or so current concrete Importers actually DOES something...but this class is just a way of running them.  I could actally make it static and pass the List into the Run method (perhaps I should!)

Comment: So, add a "known" test importer, add that to my class, check it takes "a file" and imports it to "a destination" ?

Comment: Look at Moq or equivalent mocking framework. It can set up a Mock of an IFileImporter that you can use to specify a desired behaviour (return True or False, throw exception, etc.) plus assert whether or not it's been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, yes. I can think of a number of tests right off the top of my head.

Your test ensures that all importers are called by mocking out IFileImporters you pass in the constructor. At a minimum it asserts that what you pass in the constructor are actually used by the method.

A test to ensure that if any importer that raises an exception, your class behaves as you expect.

A test should assert the behaviour if the list is empty. (default to True return?)

A test should also assert the behaviour you expect if one or more importers fail. (Are you and-ing or or-ing your importer results for your RunImporters result?)

Does the method run every importer regardless of if a previous fails, or returns false on the first failure?

There should also be a test on your constructor or Assertion for if its provided a null list.

Answer (score 2):

You can assert that the methods have been called. You can refer to these questions to see how that's done:

- [How to assert if a method was called within another method in RhinoMocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774875/how-to-assert-if-a-method-was-called-within-another-method-in-rhinomocks)
- [Rhino Mocks - How to assert a mocked method was called n-times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642801/rhino-mocks-how-to-assert-a-mocked-method-was-called-n-times)

You can also assert that no exception was encountered within the `DataImporter`class.

If you have absolute control over the interface used it might be helpful to have *each one of them* return a `boolean` indicating whether the specific operation was successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns `bool` and that's where you start, for example:

- What happens when there is no importers? Example: `Run_ReturnsFalse_WhenThereIsNoImporters`
- What happens when one of them breaks (or throws)? Example: `Run_ReturnsFalse_WhenAtLeastOneImporterFails`
- What is indicating success (returning `true`, I suppose)? Example: `Run_ReturnsTrue_WhenAllImportersSucceed`

You setup your mocks to simulate each of those scenarios and test agains that. When there's trully **no observable effects** (like returned value), you'll do it by verifying that calls were made on mocked objects.